# Flying from Dallas to Houston to Amsterdam with layover at London Heathrow around noon local time

Tags: layovers, lhr

1. Flying first class in April--the last time I went thru Heathrow there were special lines for 1st and Business class that weren't nearly as long--is that still the case?
2. Flying with AA and BA (partners) so will my bags get checked in Dallas ALL the way through to final destination in Amsterdam?
3. If it's international arrival from USA to international departure to AMS--what are the checking-in points at Heathrow (ie., customs, simple security)
4. Airline has given me 70 minutes for LHR-AMS connection (both in Terminal 5) so what's my likelihood of not having a problem? It's the ONLY flight that day therefore I had no choice.

Comment: Are you really going via Houston, as the title says? There are direct BA flights from Dallas to LHR, so going via Houston just adds complication.

Comment: Only flight from LHR to AMS that day? On a normal day there are definitely multiple flights between two of the biggest European airports.

Comment: @LassiUosukainen Most likely he meant it's the only IAH-LHR flight that day.

Answer (score 6):

1. Mostly no, since the LHR-AMS flight is on a narrow body (A32x) there will be only one jetbridge.
2. Yes, provided it's all booked on one ticket.
3. You should get all three Boarding Passes at DFW.  At LHR, you will only have to be rescreened before entering Departures.  Follow the signs for Connecting Flights.  There is transfer desk if you do need assistance.
4. The airline expects you to make it, otherwise they would not sell the ticket.  With the F Boarding Pass, you will be first off the plane and can use priority queues.

Answer (score 4):

I have entered your flights into the [Heathrow connection planner](http://www.heathrow.com/flight-connections/personal-connection-planner/BA196/BA438/11-APR-2017/11-APR-2017/5/6B) which says:

> Time needed for this connection: 60 minutes. You have 1hr 10min available.

(I know it's BA196-BA438 because a) T5 is BA only (OK, Iberia) b) there are no other 70 minute IAH-LHR / LHR-AMS BA flight pairs)

You are cutting it close but the F ticket will help cutting it. In April I'd guess your chances are good. I'd not try it in the winter but April sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

The time this goes wrong is when there is even a small delay in your departure from Houston that the aircraft cannot make up in flight.  The airspace around London can also get crowded and some flights are asked to circle in the holding pattern for a while.  As you are arriving at LHR at around midday, I would consider switching the LHR-AMS leg to a later flight to give yourself a little more time. BA0432 leaves 1hr 45min later and arrives in Amsterdam at 17:00.

Comment: The airline will rebook him on a later flight if his incoming flight is delayed; one doesn't have to do that in advance. The situation where it can be relevant to try to rebook in advance of a short layover is if you need to change to an earlier _inbound_ flight in order to make enough time.